# Parsing xml files in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have the following xml file

```
<entry>
<math marks>45</math marks>
<eng marks>67</eng marks>
<phy marks>56</phy marks> 
</entry>
```

i wish to parse this xml file in windows phone 7 such that i can extract the values for each tag, for example math marks has value 45, and save them in a variable of type double and perform some mathematical operations on the created variable.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, that isn't xml (element names can't have whitespace). It would have to be, for example:

```
<entry>
<mathmarks>45</mathmarks>
<engmarks>67</engmarks>
<phymarks>56</phymarks> 
</entry>
```

`XDocument` is supported on WP7 ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)), so you should be able to use:

```
var entry = XDocument.Parse(xml);
int math = (int)entry.Element("mathmarks");
int eng = (int)entry.Element("engmarks");
int phy = (int)entry.Element("phymarks");
```

Another option is `XmlSerializer`, also supported on WP7 ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx))

Comment: im getting an error at the line "int math = (int)entry.Element("mathmarks")" saying "Value can not be null.
Parameter name: element". what can be the problem?

Comment: use the debugger and see.  My guess is the Element name you passed in doesn't exist - maybe due to spaces (as Marc suggested already).