# How to read this little piece of XML?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I keep gettings stuck on the this XML file. I have 12 TextBlocks in my XAML, and I'd like to put every node in the corresponding TextBlock

```
<Producten>
  <Tariefeenheden>52</Tariefeenheden>
  <Product naam="Enkele reis">
     <Prijs korting="vol tarief" klasse="2">9.00</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_20" klasse="2">7.20</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_40" klasse="2">5.40</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="vol tarief" klasse="1">15.30</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_20" klasse="1">12.20</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_40" klasse="1">9.20</Prijs>
  </Product>
  <Product naam="Dagretour">
     <Prijs korting="vol tarief" klasse="2">18.00</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_20" klasse="2">14.40</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_40" klasse="2">10.80</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="vol tarief" klasse="1">30.60</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_20" klasse="1">24.40</Prijs>
     <Prijs korting="reductie_40" klasse="1">18.40</Prijs>
  </Product>
</Producten>
```

How can I achieve this?

Kind regards,
Niels

**EDIT:** I'd like to get the value of .. So, for example "9.00", "7,20", etc.

Comment: __put every node in the corresponding TextBlock__ How many textbox do you have ? If you have one textbox for each node what info (Korting or Klasse or prijs value) do you want to get ?

Comment: I'd like to get the value (so the amounts). The figures like 9.00, 7.20, 5.40 etc.

Answer (score 2):

This way you can read all the string values of `klasse`

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(YOUR XML FILE PATH);

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("Producten/Product/Prijs");
List<string> values = new List<string>();

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    var result = xn.Attributes["klasse"].InnerText;
}

//textBlock1.Text = values[0];
//textBlock2.Text = values[1];
//textBlock3.Text = values[2];
```

**EDIT:** If you are doing it in **WindowPhone**, you may use `XDocument`. Here is the code:

```
var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(YOUR XML FILE PATH);
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement item in doc.Descendants("Prijs"))
{
     values.Add(item.Attribute("klasse").Value);
}

//textBlock1.Text = values[0];
//textBlock2.Text = values[1];
//textBlock3.Text = values[2];
```

Comment: I seem to find the XmlDocument en XmlNodeList in System.Xml in Windows Phone.

Comment: see if this is helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72

Comment: Thanks for the link, but when I open it I get the following message: "You are not authorized to perform this action."

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934818/windows-phone-7-parsing-website-xml-into-xdocument

Comment: @Niels Also this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610258/parsing-xml-files-in-windows-phone-7